# Is Git Graph showing me the truth regarding commits and merges?

Tags: git

I am trying to understand the history of a project and I am using Git Graph in GitKraken to do so. I am not sure right now, whether the Git Graph is giving me the "true" history of commits and branches..

Take this screenshot as an example: it shows a commit in a feature-branch "61" which gets merged into "prd"-branch. Afterwards, there are 4 "merges" on the teal line that, according to GitKraken, is the "prd"-branch. I am now confused, if they would be working and commiting on the "prd"-branch, shouldn't those blue commit-dots not be on the teal-line, instead of the smaller merge-dots? So on what branch were they working on, that got merged to the teal "prd"-branch then? According to GitKraken it says "prd" in blue on those blue commit-dots.

What exactly am I doing wrong? I need to see, how bad or good the branching strategy is for the project but according to the screenshot alone, it would be a mess, merging from feature-branches into master/main/prd - branch.

[image]

Comment: All the dots you show here are merges, so the commits were in feature branch that has been deleted. Usually the merge commit comment should be "merge from x branch".

Comment: You can run `gitk --all &` which will show all commits involved. From the picture above I get the impression that maybe it has compressed some parts?

Comment: I don't think `prd` is a branch or any ref. A branch cannot point to multiple commits at the same time. The upper one is paralleled to a non-merge commit and the below one to a merge commit. They don't have a line linked to the commit like the feature branches do. You could use other GUI clients or the command `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` to display the graph and have a check.

Comment: @m0skit0 that might be possible but the comments are not anything like that.

Comment: @ElpieKay "prd" is a valid branch in the repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay That's just the OP moving the cursor over another commit, it's just Gitkraken pointing to another comming while having that branch checked out.

Comment: @ZesaRex Doesn't matter what the commit comments are. Those commits are the merges. They might have been squashed. In any case that structure does not show any commits in prd branch except the merges.

Comment: @m0skit0 so those merges.. there is no way to see, what branch those merges came from? As you see on the screenshot, the first merge on prd was "according to gitkraken" from "feature/61" branch. Is it just me misinterpreting this case? I need to figure out, whether there were commits to prd from feature-branches or from some long-running branches like dev or test.

Comment: I'm not a git expert, but if you deleted the branch and didn't state its name in the comment, then I think you lost that information forever. You might try with reflog, it might contain useful information. feature/61 has not been deleted, that's why it shows there. Or maybe you're filtering out branches from origin in GitKraken and that's why they don't show up.

Comment: You also might want to use `git log` on the merge commits. They should have two parent commits, one from your current branch and the other from the other branch.

Comment: @m0skit0 I have not been into the project, thats why it is hard for me to figure out what exactly is happening. Yeah, I also figured out that some feature-branches got deleted while others are still there and "old". There are certainly some problems as it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is you're trying to extract more meaning from a Git commit graph than it actually provides:

> I am not sure right now, whether the Git Graph is giving me the "true" history of commits and branches..

Note here we'll take "*true* history" to mean what the commits show us.<sup>1</sup>

**It's important to note that a Git graph shows you the history of *commits*, but does *not* show you the history of *branches*.** Since branches are just pointers to a commit, it's best not to assign additional meaning to branches beyond that. To give you a contrived example, you could create the entire history of your Git repo without ever using branches. You would create the commits and merge them into other commits and build the graph as shown. Then when you're done, you would create all of the branches to point to whatever commits they are pointing to now. The end result would be identical to what you are seeing in the graph. If you did that, you would not ask whether a feature branch was merged into `prd`, because that wouldn't make sense. Instead you would look at the graph and see which *commits* were merged into which other *commits*.

Now, of course (in real life) branches were used for those merges, but the names of those branches doesn't really matter, and cannot be ascertained by looking at the graph of the Git history. It looks like branches `feature/61...` and `feature/sen...` were (very likely) the names of two of the branches that were merged into `prd`, since they are still hanging around right now. However, you can't know with 100% certainty that that's what actually happened, since they could have been created later, or there could have been multiple branches pointing to those commits and a different branch was merged, and it's also even possible that `prd` was named something else at the time of the merge (for example maybe the feature branches were merged into some other branch, like `main`, which was later merged into `prd`).

Note you can still get some information from the graph, but it's just a different kind of information, for example:

1. The top two merges were done with a "rebase, merge commit", or, they were already up to date with `prd` at the time they were merged and a `--no-ff` merge was used.
2. The third merge from the top likely merged in from the same branch as the fourth merge from the top, as the commit getting merged in has the previous branch's commit as its parent rather than `prd`. This was not a "rebase, merge", but instead a "regular merge". (Note another possibility here is a second branch was based off of the first branch before the first branch's merge was completed.)

As for your ultimate goal:

> I need to see, how bad or good the branching strategy is for the project but according to the screenshot alone, it would be a mess, merging from feature-branches into master/main/prd - branch.

**I would not try to determine this from the screenshot alone.** If a centralized SCM tool is used you could look at the completed PRs/MRs to determine what happened and when, including what the source and target branches were, as well as which merge strategies were used.

---

<sup>1</sup> In the context of this question, "true history" means what the commits show us, which is not necessarily what actually happened in real life, because commits can be created to look like whatever the author wants. (For example you can create a commit with different time stamps, etc.) For the purposes of this question we'll assume that the commits you see are what you will base your information on, since that's the best we can do.